# Is there a way to start a DictReader at a specified line?

Tags: python, csv, syntax, filereader

I want to open a reader object and integrate until 'Transaction Date' is matched in which case use `DictReader` to get a dict object back .

```
starting=0
with open(argv[1], 'r')as file:
    transaction = list(csv.reader(file))
    #what line is the dictReader on?
    counter=0
    for line in transaction:
        counter+=1
        if line[0]=='Transaction Date':
            starting=counter-1
    
    a=csv.DictReader(file)
    
    for b in a:
        print(b)
```

Comment: Did that work? Your [mre] should include a minimal example of the csv data. Why not start with a DictReader iterate over it till your condition is satisfied then start the *processing*?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.dropwhile`, something like

```
from itertools import dropwhile


def f(line):
    return line[0] != 'Transaction Date'


with open(argv[1], 'r') as file:
    transaction = dropwhile(f, csv.reader(file))
    for b in transaction:
        print(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

Start with a DictReader; In a while loop check each *row* til your condition is met; then iterate with a for loop to process the rest.

```
import io, csv

data = '''col_a,col_b
transaction week,4
transaction second,5
transaction date,6
foo,7
bar,8
the end,9
'''
with io.StringIO(data) as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    row = next(reader)
    while row['col_a'] != 'transaction date':
        row = next(reader)
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```

Comment: Python37-32\lib\csv.py", line 112, in __next__
row = next(self.reader)
StopIteration

Comment: @YesNo - if you are getting a StopIteration *during* the while loop it means that the condition was never met and the reader ran out of lines. The solution works with **my** example data - that is why it is important that you include example data in your question - so we can test solutions on the same data you are operating on. Please read and provide a [mre].

Comment: Thank you for the reply. ill defently look into it for future refrence

Answer (score 0):

```
file = open(argv[1],'r')
# go to that line
for i in range(starting):
    file.readline()
    
# read in as dict
d = list(csv.DictReader(file))
```

---

<sub>This answer was posted as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/67591989/2) to the question [Is there a way to start a DictReader at a specified line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67591989/is-there-a-way-to-start-a-dictreader-at-a-specified-line) by the OP [Yes No](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13950242/yes-no) under CC BY-SA 4.0.</sub>